# Get video metadata with cordova-plugin-media-capture

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

According to docs there is a MediaFile.getFormatData() method that returns metadata of video file. This function does not work as seen here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4541

getFormatData() returns `{"codecs":"","bitrate":0,"duration":0,"height":0,"width":0}`.

Now is there any other way to get this metadata from a video with Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make my own Cordova plugin.

https://github.com/shahin8r/cordova-plugin-videometadata